# ReferenceError toggle is not defined | '$' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars) eslint | 'toggle' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to toggle the button to switch between an ON state and an OFF state. When the button is on and it is clicked, it turns off and the text within it changes from ON to OFF and vice versa. Now here.

**JavaScript Code**

```
import $ from "jquery";

const root = document.getElementById("root");
root.innerHTML = '<button id = "btn" onclick = "toggle()">OFF</button>';
function toggle()
{
      var i = document.getElementById("btn");
      
      if(i.innerHTML==="ON")
      {
        i.innerHTML = "OFF";
      }
      else
      {
        i.innerHTML = "ON";
      }

}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
              <head>
                <title>JavaScript App</title>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
              </head>
              <body>
                <div id="root"></div>
                <script src="src/index.js"></script>
              </body>
            </html>
```

I am trying to toggle the state each time my button is clicked, using the toggle method:
Of course I get a Uncaught ReferenceError: toggle is not defined. So how can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

```js
const root = document.getElementById("root");
root.innerHTML = '<button id = "btn" onclick = "toggle()">OFF</button>';
function toggle()
{
      var i = document.getElementById("btn");
      
      if(i.innerHTML==="ON")
      {
        i.innerHTML = "OFF";
      }
      else
      {
        i.innerHTML = "ON";
      }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
<script src="src/index.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you make it a code snippet?

Comment: have u tried to just put the toggle function above the innerhtml code? What do you mean of course u get error?

Comment: added a working snippet to your question, so it seem to be all about the importing jquery part and what exact error u get

Comment: Yes, I have used that you mentioned above but still get same error and warning **ReferenceError toggle is not defined** | 'toggle' is defined but never used. (no-unused-vars)

Comment: I am using vanilla with dependencies(package.json) 
`{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel index.html --open",
    "build": "parcel build index.html"
  },
  "name": "vanilla",
  "main": "index.html",
  "keywords": [
    "javascript",
    "starter"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel-bundler": "^1.6.1",
    "jquery": "3.5.1",
    "@babel/core": "7.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "4.17.15",
    "jquery": "3.5.1"
  }
}`